# Why would the borrow checker reject an inline expression but accept its broken down form?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

I would naively expect the two function `try_drain_*` below to have the same behavior, yet the first fails to compile while the second is executed without issue.

```
struct Container {
    map: RefCell<HashMap<i32, i32>>,
}

impl Container {
    fn try_drain_inline(&self) {
        self.map.borrow_mut().drain();
    }

    fn try_drain_broken_down(&self) {
        let mut guard = self.map.borrow_mut();
        guard.drain();
    }
}
```

The borrow checker complains about `try_drain_inline` [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5bfc851fe072d7945bff772212b32ff5&version=stable):

> ```
> error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
>   --> src/main.rs:15:5
>    |
> 14 |         self.map.borrow_mut().drain();
>    |         ---------------------        ^ temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
>    |         |
>    |         temporary value created here
>    |
>    = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
> ```

whereas it is fine with `try_drain_broken_down`.

It seems that there is an issue with the order in which the temporaries it created are destroyed; and "manually" materializing the temporaries rectifies the situation...

**Why would the borrow checker reject the inline form and accept the broken down one?**

---

*Note: my real code is a `try_pop` function which requires TWO intermediate variables:*

```
fn try_pop(&self) -> Option<i32> {
    let mut guard = self.map.borrow_mut();
    let mut drain = guard.drain();
    drain.next().map(|(_, t)| t)
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43590162/when-returning-the-outcome-of-consuming-a-stdinlock-why-was-the-borrow-to-stdin; https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21114

Comment: Maybe this is related to this: http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2017/07/11/non-lexical-lifetimes-draft-rfc-and-prototype-available/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the inline version is equivalent to the following code:

```
fn try_drain_inline_broken_down(&self) {
    {   // Implicit block around the whole expression
        let mut guard = self.map.borrow_mut();
        guard.drain()    // No semicolon here
    };                   // The semicolon is here
}
```

Once written like this you'll notice that the value returned by `drain` needs to live long enough to be returned from the block, but it keeps a reference to `guard` which only lives until the end of the block.

In your broken down version, the value returned by `drain` only lives until the semicolon whereas `guard` lives until the end of the block so everything is fine.