# match of a temporary member does not live long enough

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The following code does not compile [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1389001ee36df038d16254ccc6631a9f&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
#![allow(unused)]
use std::cell::RefCell;

enum Token {
    A,
    B,
}

struct Thing {
    c: Token,
}

fn main() {
    let a = RefCell::new(Thing { c: Token::A });

    if let Token::A = a.borrow().c {
        //Error!
    }
}
```

It fails with this error:

```
error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:16:23
   |
16 |     if let Token::A = a.borrow().c {
   |                       ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
19 | }
   | - `a` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

If I add anything after the statement, even a single `;` then it works fine:

```
if let Token::A = a.borrow().c { 
};  // Ok
```

I assume that it is because the value of the `if` is used as the return of `main`, so the borrow in the `if let` is somehow extended. But that should not happen, it is just `()`! Or is there something I'm not understanding?

BTW, the same thing happens with:

```
match a.borrow().c {
    _ => ()
}
```

Comment: I tried using `feature(nll)`, no cookie. Using `let b: () = a.borrow().c;`, the compiler wants `b` to be of type `Token` (NOT `&Token`). So we have a borrow with no outstanding reference somehow... oO

Comment: See also [Why does adding a semicolon to an if let avoid a borrow checker error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50066190/155423).

Comment: Specifically, this code works with NLL *with* the experimental "polonius" implementation (`#![feature(nll)]` + `RUSTFLAGS='-Z polonius'`).